# schedule vbscript without task scheduler

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript, Abc.vbs, which contains:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "D:\Abc.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

How do I schedule Abc.vbs to run without Windows Task Scheduler ?

Comment: Please explain why you don't want to use Windows Task Scheduler, and that will inform us of what your _true_ constraints are and allow us to make a more suitable suggestion

Comment: All you VBS is doing is running a batch file. It makes more sense to not use VBS than it does to not use Windows Scheduler

Answer (score 1):

```
'Put this code above your own code in the VBS file.
Do While(cStr(Time) <> "22:00:00") 'Please check the date/time format on your computer and make changes accordingly. This code schedules the script to 10 PM
   Wscript.Sleep = 100
Loop

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "D:\Abc.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Now double click this VBS and leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your environment, operating system, when you want it to run and what tools you have available to you.

In windows you could use registry keys or group policy to run your script at logon which can then run in a loop and then at set intervals run your batch file.

You could install an executable as windows service, which basically does what the above but uses an executable.

If you have access to SQL service it has the ability to schedule jobs as well.

There are probably a few more ways but again they depend on your specific use case.

Comment: Thank you.  I receive an error -    

Error:  object does not support this property or method: 'Wscript.Sleep'

Code: 800A01B6

Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error